# Getting 500 internal server error while using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, internal-server-error, server-error

i got an error while opening:

> Internal Server Error
>           The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>           Please contact the server administrator, admin@****.** and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>           More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  index.html   index.php
RewriteRule  history.html   historyp.php
RewriteRule  h-general.html   historyp.php?page=overall
RewriteRule  h-tajik.html   historyp.php?page=tajik
RewriteRule  h-woman.html   historyp.php?page=woman
RewriteRule  timeline.html   hronika.php
RewriteRule  t-tajik.html   tajikchron.php
RewriteRule  t-overall.html   overchron.php
RewriteRule  time.html   chronm.php
RewriteRule  heroes.html   heroesp.php
```

It works on my localhost, but when i upload it to server, it gives error like this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will occur if you have an error in your .htaccess, where error includes trying to use commands that you are not allowed to use by a [`AllowOverride` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride), so you are probably lacking a

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

in your production server config.